# Map call on a property list: control over position of value in output

Tags: expl3, latex3

Just started to dive into expl3. I have a property list and document command wrapper code. I populate the list, and traverse it with `\prop_map_function:NN`:

```
%!lualatex %
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_mwe_list_prop
\cs_new:Npn \mwe_push#1#2{\prop_put:Nnn \g_mwe_list_prop{#1}{#2}}
\cs_new:Npn \mwe_get#1   {\prop_item:Nn \g_mwe_list_prop{#1}    }
\NewDocumentCommand\mweadd{m +m}{\mwe_push{#1}{#2}} % +m = allow second mandatory argument to contain paragraph material
\NewDocumentCommand\mweitem{m}{\item[#1]\mwe_get{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand\mweitemDumb{m}{\item[#1]}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% Filling the list
\mweadd{key1}{value1}
\mweadd{key2}{value2

with

paragraph}
\mweadd{key3}{value3}

\begin{description}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_map_function:NN \g_mwe_list_prop \mweitem % Call \mweitem for all property list elements
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

- Expected output: Description-style list of `key`-`value` pairs
- Actual output: List of items indexed by `key`, but displaying `value` **twice**.
- Bad non-solution: `value` gets displayed once if I use `\mweitemDumb` instead of `\mweitem`.

Up to this, I thought I understood what happens here. But now I'm stymied. Regardless of what happens in the definition of `\mweitem`, the `value` will always be dumped into the output stream at the end of each mapping iteration step.

Which step did I miss here? I'd like to use the argument passed to `\mweitem` by `\prop_map_function:NN` like a normal macro argument, *i. e.* that I can decide by myself where to put it into the expanded code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function called by `\prop_map_function:NN` should be a two-argument function. The first argument will be passed the key, the second one the value. No need to call `\mwe_get:n`.

I changed the function names to comply with the recommendations.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_mwe_list_prop
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mwe_push:nn #1#2
 {
  \prop_put:Nnn \g_mwe_list_prop {#1} {#2}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \mwe_get:n #1
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_mwe_list_prop{#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\mweadd{m +m}
 {% +m = allow second mandatory argument to contain paragraph material
  \mwe_push:nn {#1}{#2}
 } 
\NewDocumentCommand\mweitem{m +m}
 {
  \item[#1] #2
 }
\NewDocumentCommand\mweitemDumb{m}{\item[#1]}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% Filling the list
\mweadd{key1}{value1}
\mweadd{key2}{value2

with

paragraph}
\mweadd{key3}{value3}

\begin{description}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_map_function:NN \g_mwe_list_prop \mweitem % Call \mweitem for all property list elements
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]